# How can I reorder existential variables in Coq?

Tags: coq

In some cases it is easier to instantiate the one existential term before another. In this contrived example, I wish to set `c = 3` first, and from that choose, say `a = 1` and `b = 2`.

```
Lemma three_nats : exists (a : nat) (b : nat) (c : nat),
  a + b = c.
Proof.
  eexists.
  eexists.
  exists 3.
  (* Now what? *)
```

Is there a way to use just the simple `exists 3` on `c` first?

Comment: You can always instantiate the evars created by `eexists` (see tactic `instantiate`, although I’d recommend against using it, as relying on obscure evar numbers is fragile). If you don’t want to introduce evars, you may use a rewriting lemma such as: `Lemma ex_commut {A B : Type} (P : A -> B -> Prop) : (exists a b, P a b) <-> (exists b a, P a b).` (proof is easy). But why would you need to instantiate `c` before `a`? since the goal’s head will still be an ∃, no progress can be made after having instantiated `c` that couldn’t be made before. Could you provide a more realistic use case?

Comment: One way to get around the issues with instantiate mentioned by Maelan is to use eexists with a name as in ` eexists ?[a]. instantiate (a :=1).`, but I agree with Maelan that using a reordering lemma is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that it is `enough` to prove that *there exists c,b,a such that a+b=c*.

```
enough (exists c a b, a + b = c).
```

Now you have two goals.  First, that

```
exists c a b, a + b = c  -> exists a b c, a + b = c.
```

and second, that

```
exists c a b, a + b = c.
```

Btw, you can finish off the first part of the proof quickly with `firstorder` like this:

```
enough (exists c a b, a + b = c) by firstorder.
```

Or if you don't want to repeat the goal, just apply this lemma:

```
Lemma ex_swap {A B C} {P:A->B->C->Prop}: 
  (exists c a b, P a b c) -> exists a b c, P a b c.
Proof. firstorder.  Qed.
```